# Java checkpointing

Tags: java, checkpoint

I hope my question is not too vague but I'm looking for more info about checkpointing in Java. I have to generate a big searchtree of which i'd like to be able to resume calculation after the program got interrupted (for example after a sudden reboot etc). Therefore I need checkpointing. I find very few documentation about that and I get the impression a lot of developement has stopped in the mid-90s. 
So far I've found a library called [Padmig](http://padmig.sourceforge.net/), but I hope alternatives are available? Can anyone point me into the right direction with some info about checkpointing for java?

Comment: Just a guess but there's probably not much info out there concerning checkpointing as persisting and retrieving state is typically done with a database.  Any possibility your checkpoints could be persisted in a database?

Comment: Do you mean Continuations? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe sounds a lot like [object prevalence](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-objprev/). In Java there is a library called [prevayler](https://github.com/jsampson/prevayler) that been around since 2002. I haven't used it before, but when it came our there was a lot of fuzz about it and had quite a few interesting concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support first-class continuations, so this is impossible. juancn's answer about object prevalence might help you, though.

Alternatively, if you're not tied to Java, you might use a language which does support first-class continuations, such as Lisp.